# createImage returns immutable bitmap in Android when called by another method?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am building an Android app and I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   E/AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1407)

for this line  `image.setPixel(x, y, color);`

I am using a library that wraps bitmap with Image, so it calls

```
Image image = createImage(int x, int y, int z);
```

...

```
  //this is a constructor
    private createImage(int width, int height, int imageType) 
    {
        this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, this.imageTypeToBitmapConfig(imageType));
    }
```

I tried createBitmap in my own code and creates a mutable bitmap. But when I try createImage, an immutable image is created.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these in your createImage method:

```
private createImage(int width, int height, int imageType) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = this.imageTypeToBitmapConfig(imageType);
        options.inMutable=true;
        this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, options);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is inside the library. I have no access. Is there any way to make the Image (wrapped Bitmap) mutable?

Comment: Do you have access to immutable BitMap from your code?

Comment: Yes and no.. I can have access but not before setPixel